# Top margin pulls top element

Tags: html, css

Container is pulled down when inner element puts top margin so white section appear at the top of page. How can i prevent that white section ?

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
Why there is white section in here ??
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the overflow to auto on the outer element. You're seeing [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) in your example

> **Parent and first/last child** - If there is no border, padding, inline
>   part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the
>   margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block; or
>   no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height
>   to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its
>   last child, then those margins collapse. *The collapsed margin ends up
>   outside the parent.*

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
Why there is white section in here ??
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is expected due to the [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

> The CSS box model is essentially a box that wraps around every HTML element. It consists of: margins, borders, padding, and the actual content.

Explanation of the different parts of the Box Model:

> **Content** - The content of the box, where text and images appear
>
> **Padding** - Clears an area around the content. The padding is transparent
>
> **Border** - A border that goes around the padding and content
>
> **Margin** - Clears an area outside the border. The margin is transparent

See the difference between margin and padding illustrated in this snippet:

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
}

.inner {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.margin {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.padding {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner margin">
    Inner div has a margin-top
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner padding">
    Inner div has a padding-top
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    Inner div has no padding/margin
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **margin-top:100px** on the div .inner

You can also use margin-top: 0; , or top:0; but it is not necessary...

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fw8vxpLq/)**

Try this:

```
html,body {margin:0}

.container {
background: red;
height: 500px;
}

.inner {
/*margin-top: 100px;*/
/*margin-top: 0;*/
/*top:0;*/
height: 50px;
background: yellow;
}

// ---------------      

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```